# PCB layout: Running power trace through power plane

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I'm pretty new in designing a layout.  I wonder if it is acceptable to run a different power trace through another power plane. It resides in layer 3, like the picture below. It is not high current, about 2A on the +5V plane and less than 100mA for the 3.3V. Will there be any problem, especially in term of EMC?

[image]

Comment: If high frequency current needs to flow through your 5v plane top-to-bottom: Yes, you are asking for emi trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some typical PCB layout practices are:

- ensure that the ground/power plane has good connectivity (isn't carved into small pieces)
- "sacrifice" the less critical traces first. What this means is if you have a trace/plane that is high power, high speed, or sensitive, you should route it selfishly, have less important traces take longer paths if it means that the layout of critical trace improves

Following these two practices, you should probably breakup the 100mA (less critical) trace to allow for some areas where the power plane can connect. Can make the 100mA trace dive down using vias (or even 0Ω jumpers). You can use multiple vias per layer transition if you are worried about stray resistance. You will probably want to widen the trace a bit, and make sure whatever the 100mA trace supply is well bypassed.

Below is a rough example of spots you may want to connect the 5V plane. Don't have to break up 100mA trace for all of those spots, can make it so the 5V plane is the one that dives down (just be sure to use a lot of vias).

[image]

For power traces, you shouldn't have too many issues with EMC, that is generally more of a problem for high-speed design, where traces either radiate their signal, or pick out other signals. Power planes generally don't care as much about that kind of noise.

Comment: What would be the trade-offs between breaking up the other power trace, versus using another layer to "stitch" the power plane together?

Comment: @supercat Would need more information about the PCB design and requirements. If the 100mA trace is a constant current (let's just say load is a 33Ohm resistor, and the exact supply current isn't critical) can probably switch layers liberally, as via impedance is small. If load is a high speed comparator, would need to be a bit more careful, or would need good decoupling (ideally both). 

Stitching the power plane with other layers is fine, but will likely use more space compared to changing the 100mA trace layer, as would want to use a solid fill with decent connectivity.

Comment: @supercat Without more information, I can't give a definitive answer on optimal actions. It's even possible that the best solution would be to rearrange the layout entirely, or swap from 4 layers to 8 layers. Best can do with current information is give some general rules of thumb, and have user analyze if rules apply. Unfortunately it can be hard to determine exact trade-offs/optimal actions in layout unless the design is thoroughly detailed.

Comment: @YetAnotherMichael Thanks! Sorry it took me a while to come back. I have totally forgotten I had posted this question. In my latest design, I have cut and break out the +3.3V to two different layers to make the +5V more a solid plane. This is still a good knowledge to know, as I pretty sure I will come across similar conumdrum in the future. Thanks!